# Removing items from ListView strange behaviour

Tags: listview, javafx

I am working with a ListView. Adding a new item to a ListView is easy, but how to remove one?

I build my ListView this way :

```
public Node buildListView() {
        ObservableList<String> myList =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            myList.add("Number " + new Integer(i+1).toString());
        }
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setItems(myList);

        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> (){
            @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> arg0) {
                return new listcells.ListcellY(listView);

            }

        });
        return listView;
}
```

An instance of ListcellY sets a  label in setGraphics. To remove the String associated to it from my ObservableList I add a MouseEvent handler :

```
public class ListcellY extends ListCell<String> {
    Label label;
    HBox hbox;
    ListView<String> listView;

    public ListcellY( ListView<String> listView ) {
        super();
        this.listView = listView; // Here I pass the reference to my list. Is it a gd way to do that? 
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(item!=null){
            label = new Label(item);

            label.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> { 
                System.out.println("CLicked on : " + item);
                for(String s : listView.getItems()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + s);
                }

                listView.getItems().remove(item);  // Here I remove the item form my list.
                System.out.println("list size : " + listView.getItems().size());
            });
            setGraphic(label);

        } 

    }
}
```

While this code works by removing each clicked item from my ObservableList, the listView is acting strangely. Each time a label is clicked, it successully disappears from my ListView, however a new item is automatically added at the end of that ListView, baring the name of the last label's text (but it is not a clickable label).
It keeps repeating until my ObservableList is empty. Then the ListView does not show anything.

I simply want my clicked labels to disappear, without getting any new "visual copy" in my TreeView. It is s if an index parameter is set to the original size of my ObservableList, then the ListView copies the last element until it gets the right number of elements. But I don't understand how it is done.

What can I do, what's going on in the first place?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are not removing items via attaching a changelistener to list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()?

Comment: Yep! That's because I am quite new to javafx and am not acquainted with this practice. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, seems like writing your issues makes your brain work better! I got the right intuition :
In my extending ListCell class, I check in the overriden update method whether my item is not null. but I don't handle  the case when it is null, in which case I have to set the graphics to null! I still don't understand why exactly, but it works!
Here is the updated class :

```
public class ListcellY extends ListCell<String> {
    Label label;
    HBox hbox;
    ListView<String> listView;

    public ListcellY( ListView<String> listView ) {
        super();
        this.listView = listView; // Here I pass the reference to my list. Is it a gd way to do that? 
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(item!=null){
            label = new Label(item);

            label.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> { 
                System.out.println("CLicked on : " + item);
                for(String s : listView.getItems()) {
                    System.out.println("  " + s);
                }

                listView.getItems().remove(item);  // Here I remove the item form my list.
                System.out.println("list size : " + listView.getItems().size());
            });
            setGraphic(label);

        }
        else {
            setGraphics(null);
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: "I still don't know why exactly": Say you have five items in your list; five are displayed in cells. When you remove one, you obviously now have four items but you can still see all five cells (plus some others, probably). One of those cells will be updated by having its `updateItem` method called with parameters `updateItem(null, true)`. You need that cell to remove the graphic it was displaying.

Comment: ListView uses empty cells to fill the viewport if there are not enough items. After a call to `updateItem(/* item = */ null, /* empty = */ true)`, the cell is considered empty and used to pad the remaining area.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I get it for the empty cells, but how to explain the fact that not setting the graphic to null makes those empty cells display the content of the last item?
Here I only check whether (item==null). What information could the boolean "empty" bring me?

Comment: If you don't set the graphic to `null`, the cell will keep displaying the graphic it had before, when it was not empty. The boolean flag `empty` is there to distinguish the case when `null` is a valid value for an item. It is bad practice to have `null` items, but it's not prohibited.