# ListView CellFactory - How to remove cells correctly?

Tags: listview, javafx, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` that I am working to add a `ContextMenu` to. I have the `ContextMenu` working find but have another issue.

My `setCellFactory` code, used to setup the context menus:

```
lvAppetites.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    ListCell<Appetite> cell = new ListCell<>();
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    MenuItem editAppetiteMenu = new MenuItem();

    editAppetiteMenu.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit ..."));
    editAppetiteMenu.setOnAction(event -> {
        // Code to load the editor window
        editAppetite(cell.getItem());
    });
    contextMenu.getItems().add(editAppetiteMenu);

    MenuItem deleteAppetiteMenu = new MenuItem();
    deleteAppetiteMenu.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Delete ..."));
    deleteAppetiteMenu.setOnAction(event -> {
        // Code to delete the appetite
    });
    contextMenu.getItems().add(deleteAppetiteMenu);

    contextMenu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());

    MenuItem addAppetiteMenu = new MenuItem();
    addAppetiteMenu.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Add New ..."));
    addAppetiteMenu.setOnAction(event -> {
        // Code to delete the appetite
    });
    contextMenu.getItems().add(addAppetiteMenu);

    cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());

    // If nothing selected, remove the context menu
    cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
        if (isNowEmpty) {
            cell.setContextMenu(null);
        } else {
            cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        }
    });
    return cell;
});
```

My `ListView` is searchable through a `TextField` with a listener; the listener filters the items in the `ListView` as the user types.

The problem now, is that as the list is filtered, any empty cells now display `null`.

From reading another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286355/removing-items-from-listview-strange-behaviour), I'm fairly confident that the `ListView` is still displaying a graphic for the removed cells.  I know how to handle that within the ListView by overriding the `updateItem` method, but how would I handle this from within my `setCellFactory` method instead?

Is that even possible or will I need to refactor my entire `ListView`?

Thank you, as always, for all your help!

Comment: Why not handle updates to the items backing the list cells (including item removals as they also register as updates) in `updateItem` code rather than trying to do it inline in the cell factory?  Overriding `updateItem` and handling any logic there would be the "standard" way to accomplish this, rather than through bindings and listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from the line

```
cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());
```

When the cell is empty, the item will be null, so the binding will (I believe) evaluate to the string `"null"`.

Try something that tests for the cell being empty or the item being null, e.g.

```
cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings
    .when(cell.emptyProperty())
    .then("")
    .otherwise(cell.itemProperty().asString()));
```

or (thanks to @fabian for refining this version)

```
cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> Objects.toString(cell.getItem(), ""),
    cell.itemProperty()));
```

Comment: Thank you, @James_D, as always. I had never seen the `when`/`then`/`otherwise` paradigm before.