# Javafx: bind Label text

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, bind, tostring

I want to bind a `Label`'s text to a `DatePicker`'s value, but I have a problem if there is no date selected, the label's text is `null` instead of empty string. Here is the code for my try:

```
ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
label.textProperty().bind(dateProperty.asString());
```

The `dateProperty` is set by a method, that gets the value of a `datePicker`.

The question is how can I kepp the binding but avoid null-s as text?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422674/listview-cellfactory-how-to-remove-cells-correctly/45422952#45422952

Comment: Thanks I need exactly that you mentioned in that answer.